# Data import and text to column (when in excel A1 = 1+1+1 and 3 is visible)

Tags: r, r-xlsx

Let's say we have the excel file and in **A1** we have formula `= 1+1+1`. So excel shows 3 however you can do **'Text to Columns'** and value 1 will be in **A1, B1 & C1**.

Is there anything we can do in R after data import (I use read.xlsx) to get the same result (1,1,1 as oppose to just 3)?

Just to confirm, the original *df* is 1x1 with value 3 and the desired outcome is *df* 1x3 with 1 in all 3 cells.

Comment: What R package are you using?

Comment: I use read.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the full answer, but should get you started. If we have this example file:

[image]

We can use *openxlsx* package to get the formula:

```
library(openxlsx)

# read as workbook object
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")

# get the 1st sheet
sheet1 <- wb$worksheets[[1]]

# get the cell formulas
sheet1$sheet_data$f
# [1] NA             "<f>1+1+1</f>" NA
```

Here, we can see the formula, the second item in `sheet1$sheet_data$f`. Meaning 1st column 2nd row. The rest of the job is to parse it into *data.frame* columns.

Comment: Parsed it to df no problem. Thanks again. Now I have another question if possible. How to do it with formulas are in Column B, C...I can not find any way to just import one column.

Comment: @Kalenji same method, there is an index variable showing which formula belongs to which cell. Invest some time understanding the structure of **sheet1** object. If your question is more complex/specific please ask a new question with example Excel file, and expected output.

Comment: I tried but having more then one column gives me an error in my big file. Have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753115/excel-import-to-data-frame-in-r-with-formulas) if possible.